# How to encode an array of CGPoints with NSCoder in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to save a copy of my custom class to a file, my class has 2 arrays of CGPoints which I append to every so often, they look like this:

```
class BlockAttributes: NSObject {
    var positions:[CGPoint] = []
    var spawns:[CGPoint] = []
}
```

Everything is working great as far as just as using and accessing the class goes, but archiving it does not work. I can archive arrays of Strings, Bools, and Ints just fine in my other classes but my game fails every time I try to use NSCoder to encode my arrays of CGPoints. Here is my code for archiving:

```
func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder!) {
    coder.encodeObject(positions, forKey: "positions")
    coder.encodeObject(spawns, forKey: "spawns")
}
```

....

```
class ArchiveData: NSObject {

    var documentDirectories:NSArray = []
    var documentDirectory:String = ""
    var path:String = ""

    func saveData(data: BlockAttributes) {
        documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        documentDirectory = documentDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as! String
        path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.archive")

        if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(data, toFile: path) {
            print("Success writing to file!")
        } else {
            print("Unable to write to file!")
        }
    }

    func retrieveData() -> NSObject {
        var dataToRetrieve = BlockAttributes()
        documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        documentDirectory = documentDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as! String
        path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.archive")
        if let dataToRetrieve2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as? BlockAttributes {
            dataToRetrieve = dataToRetrieve2 as BlockAttributes
        }
        return(dataToRetrieve)
    }
}
```

....
And to save:

```
let archiveData = ArchiveData()
archiveData.saveData(myBlockActionsObject)
```

I even tried creating my own custom class to save the CGPoints to, which I call MyCGPoint (I read somewhere on SO that creating custom classes for some data types resolves some NSCoder issues):

```
class MyCGPoint: NSObject {
    var x: CGFloat = 0.0
    var y: CGFloat = 0.0

    init(X: CGFloat, Y: CGFloat) {
        x = X
        y = Y
    }

    override init() {

    }
}
```

....

```
class BlockAttributes: NSObject {
    var positions:[MyCGPoint] = []
    var spawns:[MyCGPoint] = []
}
```

But alas, I am still getting this error:

```
[Game.MyCGPoint encodeWithCoder:]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x137f1d1a0 Game[20953:5814436]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '-[Game.MyCGPoint encodeWithCoder:]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x137f1d1a0'
```

Any idea how I can use encodeObject to encode my array of CGPoints/MyCGPoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert them to and from strings:

```
//To string
let point = CGPointMake(0, 0)
let string = NSStringFromCGPoint(point)
//Or if you want String instead of NSString
let string = String(point)

//From string
let point2 = CGPointFromString(string)
```

Comment: Does this function work? I am getting blank CGPoints (0, 0) every time I try to access the data. I'll play around with it some more when I get home

Comment: Works fine when I test it. The point is converted to a string with the format { x, y } which can be turned back into a CGPoint using CGPointFromString. Do you manage to get strings with the correct values from the CGPoints?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately this is not working for me. My string doesn't return in that format, it looks like this: [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0], notice the braces instead of curly brackets. I am using Xcode 7.0. I'll try updating to 7.2 and see if that makes a difference. Here's my code:                 let newPoint = CGPointFromString(block.positions[block.getPositionIndex()]) print(newPoint) let newPoint2 = block.positions[block.getPositionIndex()] print(newPoint2) the first point prints (0.0, 0.0), the second prints (129.499984741211, 31.5000171661377)

Comment: Update: I finally got it to work after a few hours by simply using NSString() rather than String() (I was reluctant to use NSString() initially). Simply changed the conversion of String(CGPoint) to NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPoint), and access using CGPointFromString(). Not sure why this works but oh well, I'm happy. If someone could explain why it does work though, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Hm, strange that String and NSString doesn't serialize the points into strings the same way. But great to hear that you finally managed to solve it. I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as accepted or at least upvote. :)

Answer (score 2):

`CGPoint` (and its Cocoa's twin `NSPoint`) are structs, i.e. value type, so you can't encode them directly. Wrap them in `NSValue`:

```
let positionValues = positions.map { NSValue(point:$0) }
let spawnValues    = spawns.map    { NSValue(point:$0) }

coder.encodeObject(positionValues, forKey: "positions")
coder.encodeObject(spawnValues, forKey: "spawns")

// Decode:
positons = (coder.decodeObjectForKey("positions") as! [NSValue]).map { $0.pointValue }
spawns   = (coder.decodeObjectForKey("spawns")    as! [NSValue]).map { $0.pointValue }
```

When you write your custom wrapper class, you have to make it compliant with `NSCoding` too, which `NSValeu` had already done for you, for free.

Comment: I tried as you said but am getting a "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error and unfortunately can't compile to test. Is {NSValue(point:$0)} correct to map an array which holds several hundred (sometimes thousands) indexes? I am getting the error on the decode line: positions = (decoder.decodeObjectForKey("positions") as! [NSValue]).map {$0.pointValue} I feel like I'm missing something but I have only been using swift for a few days now. Any help is appreciated.